# Why I can't call arbitrary function in glibc

Tags: c, glibc

I'm poking around glibc a bit and wanted to mess with some of its functions.
However I'm doing something wrong here.

A very small example calling with calling nscd_init() defined in nscd/connections.c:

```
int main(void) {

   nscd_init();

   return 0;
}
```

returns **undefined reference to `nscd_init'** during compilation:

```
# gcc -o test1 test1.c
/tmp/ccKHkJ4L.o: In function `main':
test1.c:(.text+0xa): undefined reference to `nscd_init'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

My questions here:

Is there a way how I can call glibc function in my program, or I have badly misunderstood something?

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Adding to Elizabeth's answer.

If you want to list the symbols in an .so, try using [nm](http://linux.die.net/man/1/nm). The -g switch prints only symbols available externally, while -D looks at the dynamic symbol table (which is used for dynamic links instead of for debugging). To see the symbols you can link with in glibc:

```
evaitl@bb ~/se $ nm -Dg /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6   | head
0000000000045960 T a64l
0000000000036eb0 T abort
00000000003c4be0 B __abort_msg
000000000003a620 T abs
00000000001077d0 W accept
0000000000107fa0 T accept4
00000000000f6a60 W access
00000000000fce40 T acct
00000000000fe120 W addmntent
00000000000478e0 W addseverity
....
```

As for the nscd functions:

```
evaitl@bb ~/se $ nm -Dg /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6   | grep nscd
0000000000129670 T __nss_disable_nscd
```

`nscd_init` isn't available for linking.

Answer (score 0):

glibc doesn't export every symbol it uses for public use (that is, for use in user applications). This happens to be a private symbol for glibc internal use only related to [nscd](http://linux.die.net/man/8/nscd), which you shouldn't be poking around with, and is not a terribly interesting function anyway.

If you want to find out more about symbol visibility and what it all means, [this is a good starting point](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/Visibility).

Comment: I was not particularity interested in this function, but calling internal functions in general, despite I had a feeling it is not right thing to do. Thanks for that link, will certainly read it!